# Prevent scrolling of oversized child in parent with overflow: hidden (webkit)

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-float

I have an issues with Webkit browsers. The issue happens when I focus my cursor to the `<input>` element and start to move mouse without releasing the button.

Here is a screencast - http://screencast.com/t/P1BnT7ZAdc

Here is a html/css demo - http://napokrovke.mysundays.net/webkit_bug.html

How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: What's the intent? Is the red designed to be an error alert or something?

Comment: If you're that concerned with someone being able to reposition the element, you might want to append the second bit using Javascript after they're done with the first element.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, its because you've set the wrapper to 300px, and applied the overflow property of hidden to it, which allows you to scroll around if the content within is greater than the 300px you defined, Im in firefox on OSX and I can also scroll around in it.

the only way this can be forced is maybe to apply this to the text field html markup

```
onmousedown="event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false; this.focus()"
```

this should disable the user from dragging around when selected inside the box, but then it also disables you clicking inside the box, so using focus you have to focus this box manually. but if thats what you really want?